# Passing data with delegate but still nil why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I made 2 viewcontrollers and implemented on tabbar controller. I passed some data from A vc to B vc with using delegate. When I checked the log it showed me correct value. But when I moved to B vc the value I passed was nil. (the value is for tableview.) Here is my code.

in A vc

```
-(void)passData {            
  NSMutableDictionary *infoDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [infoDic setObject:url forKey:@"file_url"];
  [downloadArr addObject:fileInfoDic];

  Bvc getDataFromA:downloadArr];
  [Bvc reloadTableView];        
}
```

in B vc

```
-(void)getDataFromA:(NSMutableArray *) downloadArr{
  self.downloadArr = [downloadArr mutableCopy];
  NSLog(@"my download list%@", self.downloadArr); // This time was ok.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   NSLog(@"Array status %@", self.downloadArr);//This time it showed me nil
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: it could be caused by weak `downloadArr` property, or maybe some other part of your code is setting it to nil. Could you provide more context ? e.g. your `downloadArr` property declaration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the array printed inside `viewWillAppear` without nil

```
NSLog(@"Array status %@", self.downloadArr);//This time it showed me nil
```

you need to  give it a value before you show bVC from aVC , whatever you use present/segue/push ,  also don't forget to declare it as `strong` , you need to do this

```
bvc = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]; 
[bvc loadViewIfNeeded];
[bvc getDataFromA:downloadArr];
```

Comment: I gave a value with [Bvc getDataFromA:downloadArr]; this. But some reason it lost the value when I moved to bVC

Comment: how do you create Bvc  in aVC and how do you present it ??

Comment: A vc, B vc are implemented on Tabbar controller in Stroryboard

Comment: so BVc tap should be clicked at least once before you can access it and send message to

Comment: [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Bvc" owner:self options:nil];  in viewDidLoad

Comment: this type of load creates another instance other than the real instance presented inside the tab , which you should access see edit ....

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try! I think you are right. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the way you move to B-VC and whether the instance of (B-VC) you used in the A -VC is same to self in the B-VC “viewWillAppear” method. 
It seems when u move to B-VC, A new instance has been created.

Or you can implement the 'setDownloadArr' method, log the value and show when the value become nil.